# How do you update a JFrame within actionPerformed()?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I added an action listener to my button:

```
myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        myButtonAction();
    }
});
```

The button will be initiating a blocking/short call. I want to update the JFrame (some of the components) before that call takes place -- to inform the user. However, there doesn't seem to be a paintImmediately for the JFrame. How should I be doing this?

At this time any changes, including `myButton.setEnabled(false)` do not get updated until *after* `myButtonAction()` is finished.

Should I really just be creating new threads for everything (non-ui related)? This seems like a lightweight task to me.

Comment: Either you task is quick/fast/lightweight and additional threads are unnecessary, either it is not quick enough and you should move that to another Thread. Just remember that you should never modify the UI outside the EDT (Event Dispatching Thread). SwingUtilities.invokeLater/invokeAndWait can help for that as well as SwingWorker.

Comment: I figured I should be using a thread -- I'm only newbish aware of the SwingWorkers so that should save me from creating and destroying threads constantly. I would like to add a question though, the button's actionPerformed is called on the EDT isn't it?

Comment: Yes of course: `ActionEvent` is an `Event` and is dispatched like all the other events, on the event dispatching thread.

Comment: Okay thanks. I was aware of the EDT and how it should be used. Obviously not intimately knowledgable though. :/

Comment: It's a good thing to be aware of the EDT and to absolutely never modify the UI outside that Thread (otherwise you are going to have unpredictable behaviour or even worse: deadlocks). `revalidate()` and `repaint()` are one of the few methods that can be invoked safely outside the EDT, otherwise, use SwingUtilities.invokeLater()/invokeAndWait(), SwingWorker or `javax.swing.Timer`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 very interesting I can understand why `repaint()` and `revalidate()` are Thread safe as it only request UI to update and does not actually change the screen but do you have any reference for this?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp "Both revalidate and repaint are thread-safe — you need not invoke them from the event-dispatching thread." -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/howLayoutWorks.html

Comment: Ahh there we go +1 thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should run it on another thread. I would not consider it to be 'lightweight' in the first place.

You may reuse threads if you want, see [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Comment: This is the answer, reinforcement of what I thought initially. But! Why would you not consider it lightweight? Let's say I have a task that takes a couple seconds. I'd like to be able to disable the button, during that time. Is it really worth creating a worker just for that?

Comment: Everything that is not guaranteed to return immediately is too slow. Even if it is not when you test it. What if your program is doing stuff in background - the VM pauses for GC - the operating system is doing stuff in background - you run on a slower machine ?

Comment: Thanks ignis. You've informed. Accepted